# Please help on One Tail Test.

Tags: statistics

A sample of 16 econ students has 3 who approval of Obama’s performance.  Test the hypothesis that the proportion is greater than or equal to .4.  Use .01 significance level and  a one tail test

What I think should be done: 3/16 and then use that number to do the one tail test.

Please let me know if I am right or wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a 1 tailed test on what?

Your sample size is too small to appeal to law of large number to use a normal approximation.
If you have, say n > 30, you can use 1 tailed Z-test

For each individual, your model is for approval of Obama is Bernoulli $(p)$ distribution, with 1 percent significance.

$H_0: p\geq 0.4$
$H_1: p <0.4$

So for 16 people the distribution should be a Binomial (16,0.4). Look up the cumulative density table for Binomial (16,0.4), which can be found http://www.pindling.org/Math/Statistics/Textbook/Functions/Binomial/binomial_16_18.htm

$P(X\leq 3) = 0.0468 > 0.01$, so you do not reject your null hypothesis.